# write console data output to a text file

Tags: java, set

The below program is done by me. If data was given as input, it will store in set display on console and write data to a text file. Please give some solution in text file. It is printing garbage values. I want the output to be printed as it looks in console.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {
        Set storeVals = new HashSet();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = "";

        do{
            System.out.println("Enter Some Data: ");
            input = sc.nextLine();
            storeVals.add(input);
        } while(!input.equals("exit"));
        //sc.close();

        Iterator storeValsItr = storeVals.iterator();
        while (storeValsItr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(storeValsItr.next());
        }

        ObjectOutputStream wr= new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("D:/new.txt"));
        while (storeValsItr.hasNext()) {
            Object o=storeValsItr.next();
            wr.writeObject(o);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ObjectOutputStream writes binary files. If you want a test file, use a BufferedOutputStream or a FileWriter

Comment: it is giving an error when using BufferedOutputStream

Comment: And the message is?

Comment: it is showing no error but the output text file is showing empty

Comment: You have consumed all values in this Loop:         `while (storeValsItr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(storeValsItr.next());
        }` so the Loop which writes it into the file will not be executed

Comment: so for printing in to file what i can i do

Comment: reinitialize the Iterator bevor the second loop

Comment: Iterator storeValsItr1 = storeVals.iterator(); like this

Comment: Yes or simply `storeValsItr = storeVals.iterator();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the JavaDoc:

> FileOutputStream is meant for writing streams of raw bytes such as image data. For writing streams of characters, consider using FileWriter.

Use `FileWriter` together with `BufferedWriter` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.krv;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class TextWriter {

private static final String FILENAME = "D:/KRV/output/new.txt";

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set storeVals = new HashSet();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = "";
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    FileWriter fw = null;
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter Some Data: ");
        input = sc.nextLine();
        storeVals.add(input);
    } while (!input.equals("exit"));
    try {
        fw = new FileWriter(FILENAME);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        Iterator storeValsItr = storeVals.iterator();
        while (storeValsItr.hasNext()) {

            bw.write((String) storeValsItr.next());
            bw.newLine();
        }

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        try {

            if (bw != null)
                bw.close();

            if (fw != null)
                fw.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Do not add code only as answer. Describe what you have done and why

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting a file filled with garbage is because you are writing `Object` to it, and not actual strings, resulting in a binary file. To fix this problem, in the bottom of your your program, consider using a `BufferedWriter` object instead.

```
BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWrite(<yourfilename>));
while (storeValsItr.hasNext())
{
    output.write(storeValItr.next()+"\n");
}
output.close();
```

`BufferedWriter` documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html